# python UDF version with Jython/Pig

Tags: python, jython, apache-pig

When I do Python UDF with Pig, how do we know which version of Python it is using? Is it possible to use a specific version of Python?

Specifically my problem is in my UDF, I need to use a function in math module math.erf() which is newly introduced in Python version 2.7. I have Python 2.7 installed on my machine and standalone Python program runs fine but when I run it in Pig as Python UDF, I got this:

AttributeError: type object 'org.python.modules.math' has no attribute 'erf'

My guess is Jython is using some pre-2.7 version of Python?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the version you are using you can do this:

**myUDFS.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

@outputSchema('bar: chararray')
def my_func(foo):
    print sys.version
    return foo
```

If you run the script locally then the version will be printed directly to stdout.  To see the output of `sys.version` when you run it remotely you'll have to check the logs on the job tracker.

However, you are right about Jython being pre-2.7 (kind of).  The current stable version of Jython right now is [2.5.3](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html), so this is the version that Pig is using.  There is a beta version of 2.7.

Comment: thanks. sys.version works. And you are right, Pig is bundled with 2.5.  So instead of figuring out a way to use 2.7 with Pig (which doesn't exist from my search), I found a way to implement the erf function in my own python code.